# How to spot mistakes in JSF pages in Netbeans

Tags: jsf, netbeans, code-assist

Can anyone please tell me the best way to spot mistakes in JSF facelet xhtml files.  On the Java side you have the compiler working for you, but for Facelet pages it seems to be just trial and error as far as I can make out.

I am using Netbeans IDE, which highlights some obvious syntax errors, but not all.

More challenging though is spotting a mismatch between the xhtml and the java bean.  Text strings are used for "El" expressions that connect to the java bean, and it seems that any mistakes in these do not show up until run-time (and then only by failure of the expected action).  Is this true?

Perhaps there are some useful tools I am missing that can do a compile-time check of the Facelet page?

Comment: Please show at least one practical usage which you assume the IDE is likely to lack the feature (with the IDE/JSF version).

Comment: Really it was a general question about realistic expectations, and whether there are some tools/tricks I am missing.  However, to give specific examples for Netbeans 8.0.02:
1) If I get a method/field name wrong I do see a little warning triangle (e.g. I typed `value="#{myBean.Result}"` but should have typed `value="#{myBean.result}"`)
2) If I get the bean or item name wrong, I don't see any warning (e.g. I typed `value="#{MyBean.result}"` but should have typed `value="#{myBean.result}"`)